# iterate over function and store all results

Tags: r, function, loops

So let's say I have a function func and I want to to call this function for a sequence of numbers.

```
func <- function (N) {
  result <- N + 3
  return(result)
}

NList <- seq(1:100)
abc <- numeric(100)
for (i in NList) {
  abc[i] <- func(i)
}

abc`
```

Now this works beautifully if the number is relatively small and the function is a simple one. but with large numbers and a more complex funciton, it takes ages. It is important to store all results of the funciton calls so I can use them in a plot against the number of function calls.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `rm(list=ls())` **NEVER EVER EVER INCLUDE THIS IN SAMPLE CODE!!!** It will cause unattending helpers to lose their own data... Read: The R inferno page 121: Your minimal, self-contained example should never ever include a line of code
like: `rm(list=ls())`  There’s a special special place for those who try to lull their would-be helpers into destroying their data.

Comment: @Wimpel I'm sorry. I deleted the part

Comment: no problem.. we all have to learn :)

Comment: try `lapply(NList, func)` It will result in a list, with the same values as `abc`. The main difference is that you call your funtion in a vectorised way, in stead of calling it 100 times for a single value.

Comment: @Wimpel Thanks! Unfortunately, I always get the Error: C stack usage  7953744 is too close to the limit...

Comment: that error cannot be reproduces with the sample data.. So I do not know where that is coming from..

Comment: As already said, it is not possible to reproduce your error with the code you provide. However, suppose the problem is the computational time. In that case, you can try to parallelize your function (see one of the packages that implement the parallel version of the `apply` family functions, such as `future`, `snow`, `snowfall` ecc...) at the cost of an higher memory usage.